# EntityFramework InverseProperty with an in-between class

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have 3 classes:

```
public class User
{
    ...
    public List<SerialHistory> SerialHistory { get; set;}
    ...
}

public class SerialHistory
{
    ...
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public SerialNumber SerialNumber { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class SerialNumber
{
    ...
    public User User { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I would really like it so that when I do this:

```
user.SerialHistory.Add(new SerialHistory { 
                                            SerialNumber = serialNumber, 
                                            DateAdded = DateTime.Now 
                                         });
```

that `serialNumber.User` gets `user` automatically assigned to it.

Is this possible or is this beyond EntityFramework's capabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no special option in Entity Framework to ensure this. `User.SerialHistory` and `SerialNumber.User` are navigation properties of two different relationships. What you have is a special business logic that cannot be enforced by a foreign key relationship in the database, hence it cannot be enforced by any mapping (that basically just represents foreign key relationships) with Entity Framework.

Your best option is maybe a special method of `User`:

```
public void AddSerialNumber(SerialNumber serialNumber)
{
    serialNumber.User = this;
    SerialHistory.Add(new SerialHistory { 
                                            SerialNumber = serialNumber, 
                                            DateAdded = DateTime.Now 
                                        });
}
```